# Variable assignment in Makefile Prerequisites

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, kbuild

I'm looking through the Linux kernel code to try and understand how the image is built.
In the `scripts/makefile.build` Makefile, there are some lines that look like this:

```
$(real-objs-m)    :   part-of-module :=y
$(real-objs-m)    :   quiet_modtag := [M]
$(multi-objs-m)   : modname=$(modname-multi)
```

They don't look like target-and-prerequisites lines nor static pattern rules.
I've been already googled a lot, but nothing seems an answer.
What do these syntaxes mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *target-specific variable values*.

From the documentation https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html

> This feature allows you to define different values for the same variable, based on the target that `make` is currently building. As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).

> There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable with their own target-specific variable value).